# Removing duplicate combinations based on the values comparison between two columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

| Row | Data A | Data B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | bbbb |
| 2 | aaaa | cccc |
| 3 | aaaa | dddd |
| 4 | bbbb | aaaa |
| 5 | cccc | aaaa |
| 6 | bbbb | cccc |

Is there a way to detect:
**1.** `Row 4` is equals to `Row 1` (because the combination of **aaaabbbb** is the same as **bbbbaaaa**)
**2.** `Row 5` is equals to `Row 2` (because the combination of **aaaacccc** is the same as **ccccaaaa**)

**End result:** *I want to keep only Row `1`, `2`, `3` and `6` in the table.*

**Note:** I would usually have more than 5k rows to check for such possible combinations listed in above example, how can I catch all the possible combinations as duplicate and keep only the unique combinations?

Comment: Do you like **deleting the duplicate rows**, or returning a list of **unique pairs**? Are there other columns after the compared one in the respective sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then this should work for you as per your requirements.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _matchOne, B2:B7&"|"&C2:C7,
     _matchTwo, C2:C7&"|"&B2:B7,
     _r, SEQUENCE(ROWS(_matchOne)),
     FILTER(A2:C7,IFNA(XMATCH(_matchOne,_matchTwo),_r)>=_r))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, DROP(A2:C7,,1),
     b, DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(c,d,VSTACK(c,SORT(INDEX(a,d,),,,1)))),1),
     UNIQUE(b))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You did not answer my clarification question related to the way of returning... The next code marks the duplicate rows **in the processed sheet** and delete them:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatePairs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngMark As Range, lastR As Long, markCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr, arrIt, arrMark, boolDel As Boolean, dict As Object
    Const delMark As String = "DMarker"

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
    
    'find the markers column header, if it exists:
    Set rngMark = ws.rows(1).Find(What:=delMark, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If rngMark Is Nothing Then 'Set the marker column it it does not exist
        markCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column + 1 'first empty column
        Set rngMark = ws.cells(1, markCol): rngMark.value = delMark
    End If
    
    arr = ws.Range("B2:C" & lastR).Value2   'place the range in an array for faster processing
    ReDim arrMark(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim markers array
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) And _
                Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2), ""
        Else 'duplicates are marked:
            arrMark(i, 1) = "Dupl": boolDel = True 'True if at least a marker has been placed
        End If
    Next i
    
    'drop the markers array content, at once:
    With rngMark.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr), 1)
        .Value2 = arrMark
        If boolDel Then 'delete the marked rows:
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Uniquify Two Columns Switched

**Microsoft 365 (Dynamic Array) Formula**

- The following applies the `U2Cols` function twice. Firstly, it performs a 'classic' removal of two-column duplicates. Secondly, it removes the 'switched' duplicates.

```
=LET(data,A2:C21,col_1,2,col_2,3,dlm,"@",
    U2Cols,LAMBDA(data,col_1,col_2,dlm,switch,LET(
            da,CHOOSECOLS(data,col_1),db,CHOOSECOLS(data,col_2),
            a,da&dlm&db,s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
            b,IF(switch,db&dlm&da,a),
        FILTER(data,IFNA(XMATCH(a,b),s)>=s))),
    d,U2Cols(data,col_1,col_2,dlm,0),
U2Cols(d,col_1,col_2,dlm,1))
```

[image]

**VBA**

- The following will remove duplicates in place i.e. **you will lose 'duplicate' rows of data**.
- The following will copy only values i.e. **you will lose all formulas**.
- **There is no UNDO.**
- It is assumed that the formatting in each cell of a column is the same.
- It is assumed that the dataset starts in cell `A1` and is in table format i.e. is a contiguous range with one row of headers.

```vb
Sub RemoveSwitchedTwoColumnDuplicates()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Remove Switched Two-Column Duplicates"
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const COLUMN1 As Long = 2
    Const COLUMN2 As Long = 3
    Const DELIMITER As String = "!?!"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
 
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long, str1 As String, str2 As String

    For sr = 1 To rCount
        str1 = CStr(Data(sr, COLUMN1)) & DELIMITER & CStr(Data(sr, COLUMN2))
        str2 = CStr(Data(sr, COLUMN2)) & DELIMITER & CStr(Data(sr, COLUMN1))
        If Not dict.Exists(str1) And Not dict.Exists(str2) Then
            dict.Add str1, Empty
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
       
    If dr = rCount Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With rg
        .Resize(dr).Value = Data
        .Resize(rCount - dr).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Switched duplicates removed.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Dictionary` object to get unique data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), RowCnt As Long, sKey, aKey
    Const SEP_CHAR = "|"
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data from active sheet
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through all rows
    ' remove "+1" if source table w/o header
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData) 
        ' Two combinations
        sKey1 = arrData(i, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(i, 2)
        sKey2 = arrData(i, 2) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(i, 1)
        If Not (objDic.exists(sKey1) Or objDic.exists(sKey2)) Then
            objDic(sKey1) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    RowCnt = objDic.Count
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 2)
    i = 1
    ' Extract unique list
    For Each sKey In objDic.keys
        aKey = Split(sKey, SEP_CHAR)
        arrRes(i, 1) = aKey(0)
        arrRes(i, 2) = aKey(1)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    ' Add new sheet to store unique data
    Sheets.Add
    ' Table header, comment it if table w/o header
    Range("A1:B1") = Array("DataA", "DataB")
    ' Unique data rows, change A2 to A1 if table w/o header
    Range("A2").Resize(objDic.Count, 2) = arrRes
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This workaround detects the reversed pairs with the following limitations:

1. Not detect the same pairs (A-B ... A-B) if in previous rows there is no any reverse pair.
2. Detect same pairs if there is a reverse pair before it (A-B ... B-A ... A-B), because there is a reverse pair before the second A-B.

Put this formula in D2 and drag down as Array formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("$C$2:C$"&ROW()),"="&B2:B7,INDIRECT("$B$2:B$"&ROW()),"="&C2:C7)
```

This results numbers for matching rows.

- Then this results (Column D) Copy and Paste Values in place to replace the array formulas with the values.
- Filter the whole table and in Column D select only the values which are not 0.
- Select all the remaining rows, and Delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a screenshot since i'm a new user. The data is in range A2:A7 (Row), B2:B7 (Data A) and C2:C7 (Data B).

This formula returns the intended output in my sheet:

=FILTER(A2:C7,(MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(B2:x,y,C2:y,x)))=0))